# Raspbian python script at boot keeps failing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cron, reboot, raspbian

Good Day All,

I am trying to run a python script at boot using Rasbian on a Raspberry PI.

I have added the following into crontabt -e:

```
   @reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py
```

That did not work. 
I then tried adding it to rc.local:

```
   # Print the IP address
   _IP=$(hostname -I) || true
    if [ "$_IP" ]; then
    printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
    fi

    /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py

    exit 0
```

That did not seem to work either. I tried adding the user and group (pi:pi) to both and that did not help.

I don't see a log for the crontab however syslog offers:

```
    Feb 21 13:44:57 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[1991]: (pi) CMD (pi:pi /usr/bin/python       /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py)
    Feb 21 13:48:22 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[1964]: (pi) CMD (pi:pi /usr/bin/python   /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py)
    Feb 21 13:48:24 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2008]: (pi) CMD (pi:pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py)
    Feb 24 07:22:18 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[1983]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py & )
    Feb 24 07:28:13 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[1983]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py & )
    Feb 24 07:34:04 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[1993]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py  )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know that the script is not run?

Comment: Sorry - I realize that may sound rude. What I mean was - what are you expecting that won't happen or how can you detect whether the script has run or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED - I think the core being here that my script is required to run in a GUI environment.

I found this solution here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

If you want a script to run when you boot into the LXDE environment, you could take a look at this Raspberry Pi forum post:

Navigate to:

```
  etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE
```

Open the autostart file in that folder:

```
 sudo nano autostart
```

Add

```
 @python /path/to/script on a new line.
```

If you want to run something like a python script, put something like @python mypython.py on a new line. Running a script file would be @./superscript, but for some reason the script runs in an infinite loop (perhaps this will stop that).

Save and exit:

```
 Ctrl+X, Y, Enter
```

Restart your Raspberry Pi into the LXDE environment.

Comment: This solution works for me, thank you @Bluedevil678. Also does the solution with a runonboot.desktop file in the /home/pi/.config/autostart/ folder. The only problem remains hiding the desktop appearing step before my app's gui.

Answer (score 0):

You added the code after `exit 0`, so it's never executed!

Use this `rc.local`:

```
 # Print the IP address
 _IP=$(hostname -I) || true
 if [ "$_IP" ]; then
   printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
 fi

 /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Midori_Monitor/Main_Midori.py

 exit 0
```

Comment: Moved the script line to above the exit 0 however it has still not run. Any other ideas? I have set the file to be accessible by all users for testing and the script runs from the terminal.

Comment: @Bluedevil678 please update your question to reflect your current setup.